# Addfieldtofilter fails if string end with ? Mark

Tags: php, magento

Mage:: getModel("core/translate")->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter("string", "How are you?");

Comment: Awesome! Now what is the question?

Comment: It returning empty collection

Answer (score 0):

The method getCollection() is not defined in core translate model , Still if you have only the issue of Question mark (?) you can try this below suggestion

Problem is when adding filed to filter the Zend_DbAdapter quoteInto remove the ?. I would like to suggest sql wildcard _ for 
?.

Please try below code.

```
Mage:: getModel("core/translate")->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter("string", array('like'=>'How are you_'));
```

You can see more detail on [Magento loadByAttribute fails on question marks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3555932/magento-loadbyattribute-fails-on-question-marks)